# Custom review form field is not saving its value in Magento backend

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, backend, forms

I have a new Email field in review form.I managed to show it in grid and in edit details page in backend .But the values i have entered are not showing in that field.It is showing a blank field. I am Currently using magento 1.9.

Comment: Clear your cache, remove `var/locks` folder and logout and login again to admin panel. It should work. If the field is still blank, add email in database table manually and check if its showing in the field.

Comment: could you tell how to add it manually using sql folder..and also there is no var/locks folder in magento root directory..

Comment: If you do not have DB access, try reindexing and then check. Also confirm if you are getting your email address in `POST` data in controller and check if the key and table column name matches.

Comment: ok let me check..